# What to do if a "question" is not a question

Tags: support, review-queues, flags

Recently I have been going through the *Triage* review queue and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122541/how-to-alter-a-big-mysql-table) question (now the question has changed, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33122541/1) is the revision I'm refering to). It clearly isn't a question so I selected "Unsalvageable" to flag it, but there is no option for "not a question".

What is the correct way to proceed here?

- Flag it as *spam*? (But there is not really an product or service promoted)
- Flag it as *unclear what you're asking*? (But there is no question)
- Flag it as *too broad*? (same as above)
- Flag it as *off topic*? (And then *Blatantly of topic*?)
- Flag it *In need of moderator intervention*?

I couldn't find a help topic or meta question on this topic so I chose the last option. Was this right or have I missed some other option?

Comment: "How to ALTER a big MySQL table without locking" sounds like a question to me...

Comment: @MarioTrucco: Please take a look at the question's revisions. The question has some "history"...

Comment: @honk I see, sorry. I did check the revision history but somehow saw only the few latest revisions. Found the original not-question now.

Comment: @MarioTrucco I now added a link to the correct revision to make it more clear.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, "Unclear what you're asking" sounds pretty close to "Not a question" to me. It's the close reason I'd use and the appropriate reason in my opinion.

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

It's not optimal - but it's "good enough" for all cases concerned.

Comment: In that sense, "it's unclear what you're asking" is just a really passive-aggressive way of saying "this is not a question". You are expecting a question, but aren't quite getting any, so you're left scratching your head as to what is being asked.

Comment: More like "There is no clear, identifiable SINGLE question here", either too many or not enough.

Comment: @BoltClock the close reasons feel passive-aggressive to me in many situations besides this one. A more honest close reason for many of the questions I vote to close would be *"This is an incomprehensible word salad"*, but that isn't available from the menu.

Comment: @Mark Amery: "salad" "menu" heh

Answer (score 3):

[Thank you, we'll take that as a comment](http://www.buzzfeed.com/tahliapritchard/11-things-that-happen-on-every-episode-of-qa-fmi7?sub=3380038_3283187)

On a more serious note, either suggest the OP split the "question" up into an [actual question and an answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), or suggest to the OP to migrate it to code review.